# How to implement two search terms React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter

How to implement two search terms in React? The first search term is name from the api, the second search term is the element's grandChild's innerHTML (the grandchild is an array of elements). The user should be able to filter the search by the two search terms together or individually.

The students array looks like this

```
[
    {city: "NY"
    email: "lily@hotmail.com"
    firstName: "Lily",
    lastName: "Yee",},
    ...
]
```

For each student, I have the functionality to add tags to them. The tags that are added to each student are html buttons. I have the function to search students by their names. I also need to implement a functionality to search students by those html buttons.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import StudentsContainer from './StudentsContainer';
import '../stylesheets/App.scss'

function App() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);

  const fetchStudents = () => {
    fetch('./url')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setStudents(data.students)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudents()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <StudentsContainer students={students} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


import React, { useState } from "react";
import Student from "./Student";
import Input from "./Input";

import "../stylesheets/StudentsContainer.scss";

const StudentsContainer = ({ students }) => {
  const [searchByName, setSearchByName] = useState("");
  const [searchByTag, setSearchByTag] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const addTagClick = (newTag) => {
    setTags((prevTags) => [...prevTags, newTag]);
  };

  const renderStudentsByNameSearch = () => {
    return students
      .filter((student) => {
        if (searchByName.length < 2) {
          return student;
        } else {
          const fullName = student.firstName.concat(student.lastName);
          return fullName
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchByName.toLocaleLowerCase());
        }
      })
      .map((student) => {
        return (
          <Student
            tags={tags}
            addTagClick={addTagClick}
            key={student.id}
            student={student}
          />
        );
      });
  };

  return (
    <section className="students-container">
      <Input
        value={searchByName}
        placeholder="Search by name"
        onChange={({ target }) => setSearchByName(target.value)}
      />
      <Input
        placeholder="Search by tag"
        onChange={({ target }) => setSearchByTag(target.value)}
      />
      {renderStudentsByNameSearch()}
    </section>
  );
};

export default StudentsContainer;


import React, { useState } from "react";

import { generateId } from "../helper";
import Input from "./Input";

const AddTag = ({addTagClick, studentId}) => {
  const [tag, setTag] = useState("");

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    setTag(target.value);
  };

  const onSubmitClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTag = {
      tag: tag,
      id: generateId(),
      studentId: studentId,
    };

    if(tag) {
        addTagClick(newTag)
    }

    setTag("");
  };


  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitClick}>
        <Input
          className="add-tag-input"
          placeholder="Add a tag"
          type="text"
          value={tag}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddTag;

import React, { useState } from "react";

import "../stylesheets/Student.scss";
import AddTag from "./AddTag";
import Tag from "./Tag";

const Student = ({ student, addTagClick, tags }) => {
    tags = tags.filter(tag => tag.studentId === student.id)
  const averageGrade =
    student.grades.reduce((acc, grade) => {
      return parseInt(acc) + parseInt(grade);
    }) / student.grades.length;
  const [isViewScores, setIsViewScores] = useState(false);

  const viewScoreClick = () => {
    setIsViewScores((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <article className="student">
      <figure>
        <img src={student.pic} alt="student" />
      </figure>
      <aside>
        <h2>
          {student.firstName} {student.lastName}
        </h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Email: {student.email}</li>
          <li>Company: {student.company}</li>
          <li>Skill: {student.skill}</li>
          <li>
            Average: {averageGrade}%
            {isViewScores && (
              <ul className="scores">
                {student.grades.map((grade, index) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={index}>
                      Test {index + 1}: {grade}%
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            )}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="tags-container">
          {tags.map((tag) => (
            <Tag tag={tag} key={tag.id} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <AddTag studentId={student.id} addTagClick={addTagClick}/>
      </aside>
      <button onClick={viewScoreClick} className="view-scores-btn">
        {isViewScores ? "-" : "+"}
      </button>
    </article>
  );
};

export default Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what are you asking. If you are simply asking how to filter an array of students with tag(s) and name, and you already know the UI part. This is how you may do it.

Since you never mention what your `students` array look like, I would assume the following:

```json
[
  {
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "tags": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2"
    ]
  }
]
```

```
const [searchByName, setSearchByName] = useState("");
const [searchByTags, setSearchByTags] = useState([]); // I don't think it is a good idea to let people to search by one and only one tag, I changed it multiple tags
const [students, setStudents] = useState([]); // all avalible students

// this is the list of student you should display in the search result
const filteredStudents = useMemo(() => students.filter(({ firstName, lastName, tags}) =>
  searchByName === "" || (firstName + " " + lastName).includes(searchByName) // include this student if the search string is empty or the full name includes the search string 
  && tags.length === 0 || searchByTags.every(tag => tags.includes(tag)) // and  if the search tags are empty or student matches all the search tags
), [students, searchByName, searchByTags]);
```

Comment: Hi @Matthew Kwong! Thanks for your response! Sorry for the confusion. I just updated my questions